# Waht does the option --sign-with in gnupg gpg2

Tags: encryption

while using the auto-completion of gpg2 with --sign- I obtained:

```
--sign-key   --sign-with
```

--sign-key is ok to me.

But what is --sign-with ?

I Found no Answer in the man page.
Has somebody any informtion about this option?

Here a few more infos

```
uname -a 
Linux mathematik 4.13.0-38-generic #43~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 14 17:48:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gpg2 --version
libgcrypt 1.6.5
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Unterstützte Verfahren:
Öff. Schlüssel: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Verschlü.: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
           CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Komprimierung: nicht komprimiert, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for [programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).